# Chrome on Android displays minimalistic list of tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android

For a couple of months now the default Chrome web browser on my Android device has changed the way it displays tabs when thr Tabs icon is tapped. Previously it used to roll out all of my open tabs in mini windows that allowed me to preview the content of the webpage and also had the title of the tab at the top of the window.

Suddenly, however, this changed and at the moment whenever I tap the Tabs icon, I get a minimalistic, text-only list of the tabs:

[image]

According to some suggestions in different forums and articles, I tried to wait it out but nothing has changed for months now. I also tried clearing the cache, disabling the application and then enabling it again but nothing has helped.

Some sources say this was a bug in the Beta of a certain Chrome version but I am well past it, currently with **Chrome 72.0.3626.96** and **Android 8.0.0**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Tabs are diaplayed the old way if I swipe down from the address bar on any tab, but this is not preferable to the normal single tap gesture. However, it is to show that the old way is still present but the functionality seems to be swapped.